# Oracle SQLInput not reading data, instead reads?

Tags: java, oracle

I have an issue related to SQLInput not reading data with readString()
Same code works on two different Oracle databases.
But on this one I have following issue:

This code:

```
@Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        userId = stream.readBigDecimal().longValue();
        name = stream.readString();
        modified = stream.readTimestamp();
}
```

returns userId and modified, but for name it returns "???" even though it has data in database for that name.
I have no idea what the issue is.
The data from query is return into oracle type similar to:

```
create or replace TYPE MY_ROW AS OBJECT (
USER_ID NUMBER,
name VARCHAR2(50),
MODIFIED TIMESTAMP
)
```

which is used in table type of that row type:

```
create or replace TYPE MY_TABLE as TABLE of MY_ROW
```

So I again, I have no idea why this doesn't work for that specific oracle database, when it works with two other ones.
It's like varchar2 fields with getString are not getting returned and I'm just getting ???

Anyone has any idea on what to do?

EDIT:
Even after including orai18n.jar in the classpath, the issue is still there

Comment: I'd guess it's a character set issue - maybe the databases have different character sets, or there are just characters in one that aren't compatible with your Java/OS environment?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolved it by combining orai18n.jar and ojdbc7.jar into same jar file.
Not sure why adding orai18n.jar separately in the class path didn't do the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).